# Quip - Salesforce Connected OAuth2 Demo

Tags: api, salesforce1-app, oauth2, quip

I am following this demo about connecting salesforce API to Quip, [Tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlMZ0VtjYqM&list=PLgIMQe2PKPSK6Z9H5vPXaSnf8LaILbDj9&index=31) or [Github link](https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/salesforce-connected-oauth2). I copied and pasted the source code, but I can't authenticate from Quip and access Salesforce API. I was successfully able to configure the Oauth2 setting in the quip console, and I see the 'Success' message when I click `Test Login` button, but nothing happens after clicking Login and logged into the prompted screen. Isn't it supposed to be back to quip and authenticate?

Anything helps, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my configuration on the Quip development console is wrong even though I got the 'Success' message. The following config is the right one:

Authorization UR: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

Token URL: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Proxy API Domains: https://*.*.my.salesforce.com https://*.salesforce.com https://*.force.com https://*.my.salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

So a good thing is that it looks like you have everything setup correctly with the Salesforce Connected App and your Live App's Auth configuration.  Otherwise, hitting that `Test Login` button would not result in the "Success" message ;-)

In your client code, when you click Login do you see an error in the javascript console?

One thing to check is that you are accessing the right "auth" setting.  I may be wrong, but the name here needs to match what you use in your Live App's Auth setup (I named mine "oauth2").

Here's a quick example.  Wire up the triggerLogin to the onClick handler of your button or whatnot.

```
getAuth() {
    return quip.apps.auth("oauth2");
}

triggerLogin() {
    (async() => {
        const t = this.getAuth();
        let _result = await t.login();
        let _token = t.getTokenResponse();

        // Now do stuff

        console.log("triggerLogin() - Logged into Salesforce : " + _result);
        console.log("triggerLogin() getTokenResponse(): " + JSON.stringify(_token));
    })();
}
```

The call to .login() will do the actual authentication check and will trigger any popup window needed.  At that point, you can make Salesforce API calls through the Quip proxy as normal.

**Note** that if you were just using the Quip Dev Console and hit that `Test Login` button, you will still have an authenticated session rolling with your SF Org in that browser.  So when you go back over to your client and do something to trigger the login call, you won't see a popup auth prompt.  The result of that login script call above though will come right back to you.

To start over from scratch and see the Auth Prompt again, you'll need to click the "Clear User Preferences" action in your Live App instance's dropdown menu and also directly log out of your SF Org instance window.

Hope that helps answer your sticking point.

Comment: Hi, Jeff, thank you for your reply. I added the code you suggested but I still can't get the return from Salesforce. It looks like it is failing at `getAuth().login()`. When I print like `console.log(getAuth().login());`, it print in the console like `Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "pending"[[PromiseResult]]: undefined`, and this pending never proceed to the next step. Do you have any idea what this is or why this happens or any thoughts about this?

Comment: Only a couple things come to mind -- You'll want to make sure to let that promise finish by awaiting for it inside that async block, or put a .then() on it to wait for the Promise to execute.

Otherwise -- if you were not already authenticated in that browser session, perhaps the OAuth login popup window is being blocked by your browser?